# can Spring boot app starts as a console or as a web app with embedded tomcat, by passing an argument?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project, I want it be able to start as a console if args indicate so, otherwise, it starts with an embedded tomcat. You can think if the app starts as console, then when you type "status", it will reply "fine" in the console. If you type "quit", the app will terminate. When it starts as web app, then when you go to url "http://localhost/stats", it will dispaly "fine" as a page. When you terminate the tomcat, that means "quit". Does anybody know how to write main class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("web"))
            SpringApplication.run(CommServerStarter.class, args);
        else
            startConsole(args);
    }

    public static void startConsole(String[] args) {
        ...
    }
}
```